# Owin response timeout

Tags: c#, owin

My Owin server calculates some data. When calculation time exceeds a few minutes,  the response cannot be written back:

> System.Net.HttpListenerException: An operation was attempted on a
> nonexistent network connection

How can I increase the timeout?

```
internal class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(Process);
    }

    public async Task Process(IOwinContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.Request.Method == "POST")
            {
                VmInventoryEstimate input;
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
                {
                    input = (VmInventoryEstimate)jsonSerializer.Deserialize(streamReader, typeof(VmInventoryEstimate));
                }

                // LONG-TIME PROCESS HERE
            }

            // TIME_OUT EXCEPTION HERE
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Body))
            {
                jsonSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, result, typeof(VmInventoryEstimateResult));
            }
        }
    ...
```

Comment: If you're calculations are taking a few minutes, it might be better to queue the calculations as a background task, and have the client query for the status of the task.

Comment: The timeout is probably happening on the client and there's nothing the server can do about that.

Comment: Amy, it would be better, but in this case synchronous processing is just fine for me. 

Tratcher, the client waits for 5 minutes, webRequest.Timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000.

Comment: @yatskovsky, Tratcher's point is correct.  Chrome's timeout can't be changed at all.  You can set the server's timeout, but that won't help you if clients won't agree to honor it, and no client has a 5m timeout by default.  You can't force clients to keep a connection open.  Also, in this case it's working just fine for you?  It doesn't appear that way to me.

Answer (score 0):

OWIN itself does not have a timeout, and most browsers (including Chrome) will wait for a very long time for the response, they have to do this support long poll techniques.

I think your timeout is most likely coming from your web server. For example if you are using IIS then you can configure this for the App Pool.

If you are not using IIS then please let us know your setup so we can help you further.